# i want to take input from users as a list but i get an error

Tags: python, list, input

```
lst = int( input("Enter list values : "))

def count(lst):
    even = 0
    odd = 0

        for i in lst:


                if i%2 ==0:
                    even+=1
                else:
                    odd+=1

        return even,odd
print(even,odd)



even,odd = count(lst)

print("Even : () Odd : () :".format(even,odd))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Judging by the code, I presume the error is on line 1 with `lst = int( input("Enter list values : "))` .  `int()` is a built-in function that converts parameters into integers, not lists. Furthermore in what format is the input e.g. comma separated etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = input("Enter list values : ").split()
lst_to_int = [int(x) for x in lst]
even = 0
odd = 0
for i in lst_to_int:
    if i%2 ==0:
       even+=1
    else:
       odd+=1
print(even, odd)
print("Even : ("+str(even)+") Odd : ("+str(odd)+")")
```

I decided to simply your code to make it easier to read. First take in the list of input as `str`, then convert it to `int` by list comprehension. After that iterate through `lst_to_int` and count the number of evens and odds. Then print it out.

Hope it helps :)

EDIT: Requested from OP's comments to also answer  using function. Here is the code:

```
def count(even, odd, lst_to_int):
    for i in lst_to_int:
        if i%2 ==0:
           even+=1 
        else:
           odd+=1
    print(even, odd)
    print("Even : ("+str(even)+") Odd : ("+str(odd)+")")
even = 0
odd = 0 
lst = input("Enter list values : ").split()
lst_to_int = [int(x) for x in lst]
result = count(even, odd, lst_to_int)
```

Comment: but how can i create same program using function

Comment: @DineshKatariya Done :)

Answer (score 1):

`input` evaluates the specified string given as input. So the specified string has to be a valid python expression.

To get a list, you can specify the input as a list explictly

```
>>> lst = input("Enter list values : ")
Enter list values : list([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Alternatively, you can use `raw_input` to get a string, `split` the string and `map` each element to an `int`

```
>>> lst = map(int, raw_input("Enter list values : ").split())
Enter list values : 1 2 3 4 5 6
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Can use `split(',')` for comma separated inputs

Comment: Why `raw_input` and not just `input`?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    lst = input("Enter list values : ")

    def count(lst):
        even = 0
        odd = 0
        for i in lst:
            if i%2 ==0:
                even+=1
            else:
                odd+=1
        return even,odd

    even,odd = count([int(val) for val in lst.split(',')])
    print("Even : {even} Odd : {odd} ".format(even=even,odd=odd))
```

Comment: your edited code gives below err   ==>    even,odd = count([int(val) for val in lst.split(' , ')])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '110 20 30'

Comment: Enter list values : 10 20 30 40 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dinesh Katariya/Desktop/py/list_function.py", line 15, in <module>
    even, odd = count([int(val) for val in lst.split(',')])
  File "C:/Users/Dinesh Katariya/Desktop/py/list_function.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    even, odd = count([int(val) for val in lst.split(',')])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 20 30 40 '

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please enter values as 10,20,30,40

Comment: ohh txx its my mistake